# Interact with notification action from ADB Shell

Tags: adb, notifications, usb-debugging, shell

I have an Android(7) phone [also fine if you can provide a solution for Android 10] and a Linux pc. By enabling USB debugging and using the terminal of my pc, I am able to read the notifications of my phone using the command: `adb shell dumpsys notification --noredact`

Now, there are some notifications in android in which we can interact with the app directly from the notification. For example, in a Whatsapp notification, there are usually two buttons: *Reply* & *Mark as read*. In YouTube, there are options like *Play, Turn off, Watch later*. In the output of the above command, these options are visible in the following form:

```
actions={
        [0] "Reply" -> PendingIntent{6becf48: PendingIntentRecord{87b8050 com.whatsapp startService (whitelist: +30s0ms)}}
        [1] "Mark as read" -> PendingIntent{c1661e1: PendingIntentRecord{b8e3249 com.whatsapp startService (whitelist: +30s0ms)}}
      }
```

I have two questions:

1. Can we interact with these options from adb shell? For example, is there any command like `adb shell <SOME COMMAND> 'Message to be sent in whatsapp with reply option'` which will send the text as a reply in whatsapp without opening the app?
2. Is it possible to swipe the notifications using any adb command? (Not the `adb shell input swipe x0 y0 x1 y1`, it requires to unlock the phone each time)

Thank you in advance!

**Edit:**

Here is what I found that may be relevant to this question.

I think that I have to somehow launch the specific intent linked to the mentioned PendingIntent id (in this case `6becf48` or `87b8050`)

Using tthe command `adb shell dumpsys activity intents > output.txt` and then searching for `87b8050` in `output.txt`, I found the name of the intent. It was as follows:

```
  * PendingIntentRecord{87b8050 com.whatsapp startService (whitelist: +30s0ms)}
    uid=10104 packageName=com.whatsapp type=startService flags=0x0
    requestIntent=act=com.whatsapp.intent.action.DIRECT_REPLY_FROM_MESSAGE dat=content://com.whatsapp.provider.contact/contacts/2256 cmp=com.whatsapp/.notification.DirectReplyService (has extras)
    whitelistDuration=+30s0ms
```

Now I think that it may be possible to launch the intent `com.whatsapp.intent.action.DIRECT_REPLY_FROM_MESSAGE` using `adb shell am` command, and passing the intent id and message as some parameters.

(Just like we can launch Whatsapp from adb with `am` command, it should be possible to launch the pendingIntent also.)

**Edit 2:**

Using this command:

```
adb shell am startservice -a com.whatsapp.intent.action.DIRECT_REPLY_FROM_MESSAGE -d content://com.whatsapp.provider.contact/contacts/2256 -n com.whatsapp/.notification.DirectReplyService --es 'com.whatsapp.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT' 'Hi. Okay.'
```

The output was following:

```
Starting service: Intent { act=com.whatsapp.intent.action.DIRECT_REPLY_FROM_MESSAGE dat=content://com.whatsapp.provider.contact/contacts/2256 cmp=com.whatsapp/.notification.DirectReplyService (has extras) }
Error: Requires permission not exported from uid 10104
```

Comment: I too am interested in this question.. I currently use "Automate" app for automatically interacting with my notifications(if that helps)

Comment: Thanks for the information, I shall check this out. But as it seems, the app requires a lot of permissions. It'd be nice if we can do it from our adb terminal.

Comment: No, it doesn't. That's what i like about this app. Just deny all the permissions at the start and then afterwards it will ask for one or two necessary permissions. I too am too paranoid about my privacy. This app lists all the permissions it has and you can anytime revoke permissions you don't want anymore. Disable the internet access for additional security. I'll search about the adb thing too tho.. BTW why dont you try scrcpy(just for fun). I just love scrcpy and use it very often with adb over wifi. https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy

Comment: Scrcpy is a very nice thing. I had not heard of it before. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're most welcome. Btw i searched the web and came to a conclusion that there isn't a way yet to do what you want.. I searched for all adb and notification related stuffs and found that you can only list(dumpsys) and clear(requires root) notifications NOT interact sadly. Hope you can do it with scrcpy graphically.. P.S. See scrcpy's command list.

Comment: I understand that this has not been mentioned explicitly anywhere. But I still believe this is doable. Please see my recent edit to the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115702/discussion-between-soham-saha-and-aayush).

Comment: I found a way.. it's a little long but possible.. Remember automate app i mentioned? it can interact with notifications.. So.. by dumpsys you can know what notifications came and then you can send notification of message you want to reply from adb to your device. The automate app will then pick the notification you sent from adb and forward it to whatsapp(as it can interact with notifications)

Comment: Hello. It would be nice if you mention why must you interact with the Android's notifications with ADB alone? Would it not be acceptable if a solution emerges wherein you instruct a third-party app (through ADB) to do the job for you. That is, read the notification and show it to your Linux PC, and send the reply message from your ADB to the target app.

Comment: Also, there is this [KDEConnect app](https://nicolasfella.wordpress.com/2018/03/20/kde-connect-state-of-the-union) (see *Reply to Whatsapp and others* subheading) which seems to promise replying to WhatsApp from your PC. I know it can sync notifications but I never tried its reply feature. You can give it a try.

Comment: Third, if you don't want an automate app and scrcpy solution is not acceptable either, I can offer a bounty on your question so that your question receives more attention. Let me know if you are interested.

Comment: @Firelord , it would be okay if it is necessary to implement through an external app. But given the versatile collection of ADB commands (and lack of broad description/tutorials :-) ), I have an impression that this can be done with a few line of commands. In that case, I would obviously prefer the 'ADB only solution' over any third party app. Automate, scrcpy and KDEConnect are nice alternatives. I have aready tried scrcpy, it is very useful. But it would be better if this can be achieved with ADB only. I would be very grateful if you please offer a bounty on this question.